# How to set default opener

Tags: default

I am currently programming a website using html , CSS, and php.

If I ever directly open a file, it will open with the Brackets code editor application. Now I prefer to use atom.io or would want to open the file with google chrome.

Is it possible to set the default opener to the preferred one?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: OS X on a Mac desktop computer

Comment: Yes it is... Deleting is the thing to do right?

Comment: No, just let it get flagged as duplicate. So if other people can find that answer if they would write it the same way as you.